# Writing Elasticsearch Nest Bool query with Must Field value

Tags: elasticsearch, .net-core, nest

I'm trying to reproduce the following query which works great in Kibana:

```js
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "title": "fake"
          }
        }
      ],
      "filter": {
        "term": {
          "roleIds": "af54122f-8d99-47e5-9e5a-88659a1229d4"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Here's my attempt in .NET:

```cs
ISearchResponse<T> response = await client.SearchAsync<T>(s => s
    .Query(q => q
        .Bool(b => b
            .Must(m => m
                .Match(t => t
                    .Field(new Field("title"))
                    .Value("fake") // "Value" is red.
                ))
        .Filter(f => f
            .Term(t => t
                .Field(new Field("roleIds")).Value(RoleId))) // Value works here.
          ));
```

Value doesn't work here. The compiler error is:

```
Error   CS1061  'MatchQueryDescriptor<T>' does not contain a definition for 'Value' and no accessible extension method 'Value' accepting a first argument of type 'MatchQueryDescriptor<T>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

How do I write the equivalent of `bool > must > match > title: val`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply replace `.Value("fake")` with `.Query("fake")`. As a side note, you can siplify `.Field(new Field("title"))` with `.Field("title")`.

Hope that helps.